# ECDSA signing file with key from store C#.Net CNG

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, elliptic-curve, cng

I'm trying to sign a file with ECDSA using the CNG API and a certificate from the Microsoft Certificate Store. I've read through a lot of documentation and and near done but I get hung up on importing the private key from the certificate. I've done this very same thing with RSA but it appears to be done very differently. Here's the code I have so far:

```
    static void signFile()
    {
        X509Certificate2 myCert = 
             selectCert(StoreName.My, 
                        StoreLocation.CurrentUser, 
                        "Select a Certificate",
                        "Please select a certificate from the list below:");

        Console.Write("Path for file to sign: ");
        string path = Console.ReadLine();
        TextReader file = null;
        try
        {
            file = new StreamReader(path);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.Write("\nPress any key to return to the main menu: ");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(file.ReadToEnd());
        ECDsaCng dsa = new ECDsaCng(
            CngKey.Import(StringToByteArray(myCert.PrivateKey.ToString()),
                          CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPrivateBlob,
                          CngProvider.MicrosoftSoftwareKeyStorageProvider));

        dsa.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha384;
        byte[] sig = dsa.SignData(data);
        TextWriter signatureFile = new StreamWriter("signature.txt");
        signatureFile.WriteLine("-----BEGIN SHA384 SIGNATURE-----" + 
                                ByteArrayToString(sig) + 
                                "-----END SHA384 SIGNATURE-----");
        signatureFile.Close();
    }
```

And I get the error

> System.NotSupportedException: The certificate key algorithm is not supported.

My certificate is ECDSA_P256 sha384ECDSA with the following extensions:

```
Digital Signature, Non-repudiation, independent signing revocation list (CRL), CRL Signing (CRL) (c2)
Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1)
Client Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2)
Code Signing (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3)
Unknown Key Usage (1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.22)
Unknown Key Usage (1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.21)
IKE-intermediary IP-security (1.3.6.1.5.5.8.2.2)
```

It would appear as if the certificate was the problem but I'm not sure if it could be the code or not.

---

Here's my certificate with the public key:

```
Certificate:
Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number: 2 (0x2)
Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA384
    Issuer: C=##, O=#######, OU=#####, OU=#####, CN=###########
    Validity
        Not Before: Apr 27 16:35:51 2012 GMT
        Not After : Apr 26 16:35:51 2017 GMT
    Subject: C=##, O=###########, OU=#####, CN=#############
    Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
            Public-Key: (256 bit)
            pub:
                04:fc:d5:ce:ad:1f:0c:19:b9:3d:2b:bd:7d:f0:8c:
                44:46:db:e3:42:14:b1:1a:9f:7c:ab:e1:be:ad:a5:
                0c:03:2d:0f:ff:3f:10:d4:69:eb:4c:82:a1:2a:61:
                56:45:03:04:a6:49:f7:16:6e:dd:60:22:c6:20:c5:
                4d:44:49:21:41
            ASN1 OID: prime256v1
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Key Usage: critical
            Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, CRL Sign
        X509v3 Extended Key Usage: critical
            TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication, Co
de Signing, Microsoft Commercial Code Signing, Microsoft Individual Code Signing
, 1.3.6.1.5.5.8.2.2
        X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
            DirName:/C=##/O=#######/OU=#####/OU=#####/CN=######
            serial:01
        X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
            B7:A8:F9:55:9A:43:9E:BE:1C:4B:62:52:91:C2:F1:39:72:E1:CE:1B
        X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
            CA:FALSE
Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA384
     30:81:88:02:42:01:75:55:f3:64:f9:aa:2a:66:55:b1:ca:dc:
     86:ac:1f:7d:2a:ec:10:87:db:74:88:0e:77:e3:18:82:15:a7:
     32:91:1a:2d:ea:07:2e:78:8d:dc:8a:18:3c:2b:5a:9b:6a:0f:
     97:f6:f8:8d:c5:fc:0e:9f:20:e9:b0:16:90:1a:c4:58:ac:02:
     42:01:dc:b3:88:ae:44:54:c4:e0:b7:c2:37:88:0b:19:6b:96:
     99:f7:21:12:45:12:21:e5:ab:83:39:a6:47:3a:08:87:b0:fa:
     0e:31:1b:97:83:8d:65:30:a1:43:c1:82:27:77:6e:93:89:1b:
     bd:57:b1:7a:54:9e:cc:e1:44:cc:74:16:c5
```

Comment: Microsoft has pretty limited Elliptic Curve Cryptography (ECC) support. It only provides "elliptic curve DSA (ECDSA) over the NIST-standard prime curves P-256, P-384, and P-521." and those should be "named" curves. Do you know which EC domain parameters are in the certificate? Alternatively you may paste the hexadecimal, base64 or ASN.1 text of the certificate so we can find out.

Comment: You may edit your question instead of answering to provide more info. Re-reading the question, a certificate itself does not contain the private key. Generally you create a key pair, create a certificate request containing the public key and sign that with the private key. Then the CA bakes a certificate from it and sends it back. That certificate only contains the public key. So when you try to import the private key, in what format is it? PKCS#12? That would be either the `.pkf` or `.p12` file extensions.

Comment: Ah, I see where you go wrong, should have put my glasses on. ToString does not encode the private key. It simply prints some info on the private key. You may use the `DSACryptoServiceProvider` that the PrivateKey property actually extends instead of encoding/reencoding the private key.

Comment: So would I use the `DSACryptoServiceProvider` to actually complete the signing or just merely handle the importing of the EC key? If you could provide some sample code, I'd love to finally mark this as solved. Thanks again for the help by the way.

Comment: Additionally, the public key algorithm property is correct according to the Internet Engineering Task Force (http://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc3279#page-13) so it seems like it's a problem with Microsoft. I tested a Microsoft sample program (lost the URL) where I encountered the same error. It seems they in fact CANNOT support ECC unlike what http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204775(v=vs.85).aspx#suite_b_support says

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? Could you post your solution?

Answer (score 7):

I've been battling ECDsa and CngKey with X509 certificates for a looong time and had the exact same issues. We ended up creating our own CngKeys with ECDsa_P256 SHA256, but I do believe that i learnt something digging in to CryptoApi:

When you have a certificate that is marked with "Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1)" (use as SSL certificate), your certificate will contain the key exchange algorithm ECDH. And somehow this "takes precedence" over the ECDsa algorithm group. Thus you get the dreaded "The certificate key algorithm is not supported".

I spent over an hour with Symantec looking over my shoulder and they could not solve the puzzle, so they gave up with a "Sorry, we don't support use of SSL certs for anything but SSL".

You can get your private CngKey from the cert with CLRSecurity from Codeplex (http://clrsecurity.codeplex.com/). This gives your x509Certificate2 an extension that allows for this code:

```
X509Certificate cer = <getyourcertcode>;
CngKey k = cer.GetCngPrivateKey();
```

Inspect "k" and see that your algorithm group is probably something else than expected. Mine was ECDH...

Solution I am trying now is to set up a new CA server force it to do exactly what I want. Basically that would be an X509 cert that is ONLY used for code signing...

"X509v3 Key Usage: critical Digital Signature" might have to be the ONLY usage allowed...

Hope this helps someone else out there :-)

Comment: How do you go about creating a CngKey from just a public key?  That CLRSecurity library doesn't seem to provide an `GetCngPublicKey()` extension.  How can I verify an ECDsa signature with just the signer's public key in an X509Certificate in the cert store?

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264770/creating-an-ecc-private-public-key-with-native-c-sharp/22637599#22637599. Verify like this: using (ECDsaCng ecsdKey = new ECDsaCng(CngKey.Import(key, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob)))
        {
            if (ecsdKey.VerifyData(data, signature))
                Console.WriteLine("Data is good");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Data is bad");
        }

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to have anything do with X509Certificates in the cert store?

Comment: GOD BLESS YOU! I searched for over 4 hours around internet to find how to get the friggin private key out of the certificate!! Your link to the codeplex Security assembly was what I'd been looking for!!

Answer (score 7):

.NET 4.6.1 solved the core needs of this problem.  The new code would be

```
...
byte[] sig;
using (ECDsa ecdsa = cert.GetECDsaPrivateKey())
{
    if (ecdsa == null) throw new Exception("Not an ECDSA cert, or has no private key");

    sig = ecdsa.SignData(data, HashAlgorithmName.SHA384);
}
```

.NET 4.6.1 also fixed the issue where some cert keys come back as ECDH and thus fail.  (Well, it didn't solve the problem of some private keys being considered ECDH -- which had nothing to do with the Server Auth EKU, but was a good guess -- but considers those keys to be valid now).

Answer (score 2):

If you are running Windows Vista or Windows 2008, the CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPrivateBlob is not supported. What OS are you using?
[CngKey.Import throws CryptographicException only on some machines](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/netfxbcl/thread/aaa10f81-6296-4768-a948-edb3449550de)

Comment: I was using Windows 7 but now I've "upgraded" to 8.

Comment: Ok, you can ignore my answer since that issue won't happen in Windows 7, and presumably it won't happen in Windows 8 either.