# How do I create self signed certificate with id-ecc for use with ECDSA signature and verification?

Tags: .net-core, cryptography, public-key, .net-4.6, self-signed-certificate

I'm trying to update [this article's code](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dcook/2008/11/25/creating-a-self-signed-certificate-in-c/) to allow me to create (and use) an ECC based self signed certificate, and [do basic signing and verification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10490263/10089398) with it ([ECDSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/12829/64383)).

- Is there any way to accomplish this with cross platform .NET Core APIs, or is Win32 P/Invoke required?

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47124033/10089398), I need to use `the more standard id-ecc`type

Comment: Do you really need to create certificate with C# code? It will be much simpler to do this with openssl command line API

Comment: @Zergatul OpenSSL isn't approved for use in the highly controlled environment I'm working with (neither is Bouncy Castle)

Comment: Do you need to generate a lot of certificates on the fly? If not, you can generate certificate once with openssl and then use it in C#.

Comment: openssl (and bouncy castle) are not permitted in the restricted environment I'm working in. @Zergatul

Comment: Well, if you cannot use libraries then you may have to program it yourself, don't you? I'd ask for a exception to that rule, because programming certificates - with all the ASN.1 involved - just isn't any fun. BC has a permissive license, so you could just copy the relevant parts  (with proper contribution statement towards BC, of course). Warning: that may take some time to extract, it would be a lot of code. You might also want to look into the .NET code itself, it is also O/S licensed nowadays (I think, IANAL).

Comment: The answer says you can do ECDSA /unless/ you use id-ecDH.

Comment: @bartonjs Thank you for clarifying this. I updated the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any way to accomplish this with cross platform .NET Core APIs

Yep!

```cs
X509Certificate2 cert;

using (ECDsa key = ECDsa.Create(ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256))
{
    CertificateRequest request = new CertificateRequest(
        "CN=Self-Signed ECDSA",
        key,
        HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);

    request.CertificateExtensions.Add(
        new X509KeyUsageExtension(X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature, critical: false));

    request.CertificateExtensions.Add(
        new X509BasicConstraintsExtension(false, false, 0, false));

    // If it was for TLS, then Subject Alternative Names and
    // Extended (Enhanced) Key Usages would also be useful.

    DateTimeOffset start = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

    cert = request.CreateSelfSigned(notBefore: start, notAfter: start.AddMonths(3));
}

// If you want to save a PFX or something, you can do so now.
```

Comment: Requires .NET 7.1.  I hope I can make a convincing enough argument to switch!